# How to Solve Too Many Files Open Error from Socket Program without Setting ulimit -n

Tags: c++, sockets, ulimit

I am currently coding a socket server and client in C++. My goal is to have a server kept running, while clients should terminate as it sends and receives message from server.

Everything works well until the client is called around 1000 times, and crashes with too many open files error. I have found the reason is the setting of **ulimit -n**, whose default value is 1024.

Most solutions I found tell us to set a higher ulimit value. However, I am not sure if this is proper:

1. it might mean that there is a bug in my code
2. ulimit is there to protect our machine, setting it too high is just like disabling the protection
3. there is still a chance to reach the limit, assuming the server is running for weeks or months, the problem is not solved

I tried a few socket examples on the web but they have similar problems, say [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/socket-programming-cc/) for example.

**Question:**

1. **Is there any way to avoid this error? Is there anything wrong in the code?**
2. **Is setting ulimit -n a high value harmful, say 1048576?**

Thank you.

My working codes are as follows:

server.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/socket.h> //sockaddr
#include <sys/un.h> //for sockadder_un
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h> //unlink
#include <signal.h> //for catching ctrl+c

bool keep_running = true;
void terminate(int i) {
  keep_running = false;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv[]) {

  //--catch ctrl+c signal
  struct sigaction sigIntHandler;
  sigIntHandler.sa_handler = terminate;
  sigemptyset(&sigIntHandler.sa_mask);
  sigIntHandler.sa_flags = 0;
  sigaction(SIGINT, &sigIntHandler, NULL);

  //--create socket
  int socket_fd_server = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (socket_fd_server >= 0) {
    std::cout << "Server socket created" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Server socket failed to create, errno: " << errno << std::endl;
  }

  //--bind server
  sockaddr_un address_server;
  address_server.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  strcpy(address_server.sun_path, "./socket-server");
  unlink(address_server.sun_path); //delete socket file if exists

  //will create a socket file, if already exist, errno=98
  if (bind(socket_fd_server, (sockaddr*)&address_server, sizeof(address_server)) >= 0) {
    std::cout << "Server bound" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Server failed to bind, errno: " << errno << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  //--mark socket as passive socket (listen)
  if (listen(socket_fd_server, 100) >= 0) {
    std::cout << "Start to listen" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Failed to listen, errno: " << errno << std::endl;
  }

  //--
  sockaddr_un address_client;
  char message_sent[] = {"message from server to client"};
  char message_received[100] = {};
  while (keep_running) {
    unsigned int len = sizeof(address_client);
    int socket_fd_client = accept(socket_fd_server, (sockaddr*)&address_client, &len);
    send(socket_fd_client, message_sent, sizeof(message_sent), 0);
    std::cout << "Server sent message: " <<message_sent << std::endl;
    recv(socket_fd_client, message_received, sizeof(message_received), 0);
    std::cout << "Server received message: " <<message_received << std::endl;
  }
  std::cout << "Leave while loop" << std::endl;
  unlink(address_server.sun_path);
  close(socket_fd_server);
  return 0;
}
```

client.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h> //see NOTES in http://www.linuxhowtos.org/manpages/2/connect.htm
#include <sys/socket.h> //sockaddr
#include <sys/un.h> //for sockadder_un
//#include <netinet/in.h> //for sockadder_in
#include <unistd.h> //close
#include <errno.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv[]) {

  //--create socket
  int socket_fd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
  if (socket_fd >= 0) {
    std::cout << "Client socket created" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Client socket failed to create, errno: " << errno << std::endl;
  }

  //--connection
  sockaddr_un address_un;
  address_un.sun_family = AF_UNIX;
  //address_un.sun_path = "./SocketServer";
  strcpy(address_un.sun_path, "../SocketServer/socket-server");
  if (connect(socket_fd, (sockaddr*)&address_un, sizeof(address_un)) == 0) {
    std::cout << "Client connected" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Client failed to connect, errno: " << errno << std::endl;
  }

  //--send message
  //char message_sent[] = {"test send message"};
  std::string message_sent = "test send message";
  if (send(socket_fd, message_sent.c_str(), sizeof(message_sent), 0) > 0) {
    std::cout << "Message: " << message_sent << " sent" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Message: " << message_sent << " not sent, errno: " << errno << std::endl;
  }

  //--receive message_sent
  char message_received[100] = {}; // = "test receive message";
  if (recv(socket_fd, message_received, sizeof(message_received), 0) > 0) {
    std::cout << "Message: " << message_received << " received" << std::endl;
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Message: " << message_received << " not received, errno: " << errno << std::endl;
  }

  //--close
  close(socket_fd);

  return 0;
}
```

BTW, this only happens when the server is run in bash. If the server is run in Eclipse debugger, it can exceed 1024 calls. I do not know why.

Comment: in the server you aren't closing socket from the clients you accept

Comment: in the client you are doing `sizeof(message_sent)` wich will return the size of the `std::string` object not the data it represent what you want to do i think is `message_sent.size()`

Comment: @Tyker Thank you. Do you mean to put close(socket_fd_server); inside the loop? I tried and it surely doesn't keep opening files, but not it keeps running in loop, any hints?

Comment: `close(socket_fd_server);` in the loop will fail because you can't use a socket after closing it but `close(socket_fd_client);`in the loop after you don't use `socket_fd_client` should work

Comment: @Tyker Thanks a lot! This solves the problem. Would you mind to put an answer so I can accept it? BTW, since we `close(socket_fd_client);` in server.cpp, is `close(socket_fd);` in client.cpp redundant thus could be removed?

Comment: closing the file descriptor on the client side isn't redondant because it is in two different processus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in the server you are not closing file descriptors of the client you accept to do so

```
  while (keep_running) {
    unsigned int len = sizeof(address_client);
    int socket_fd_client = accept(socket_fd_server, (sockaddr*)&address_client, &len);
    send(socket_fd_client, message_sent, sizeof(message_sent), 0);
    std::cout << "Server sent message: " <<message_sent << std::endl;
    recv(socket_fd_client, message_received, sizeof(message_received), 0);
    std::cout << "Server received message: " <<message_received << std::endl;
    close(socket_fd_client); //close the file descriptor
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

You're leaking sockets. Try some error checking. There is not enough here. If `recv()` returns zero, close the socket. If it returns -1 and `errno`is not `EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK`, close the socket. If `send()` returns -1, close the socket.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I will take a look a it :)